# variable not available after for-loop inside Promise.then()

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, scope

I'm using a for-loop containing an if statement inside of a Promise.then() (it's an api call). A variable initialized before the for-loop is available within the for-loop, but not after.

I've console.logged the variable before the for-loop, just inside the for-loop, inside the if statement, after the if statement, and after the for-loop. That last console.log doesn't even come up undefined. It just doesn't seem to register at all.

I've tried simple versions of the same basic structure in the Chrome console and it works, but the difference is that in the Chrome console I'm not within a Promise.then(). So I think there's something I'm not understanding about it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const url = 'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46029.spec';
  const newBouyData = new BouyData();

  let currentBouyData = newBouyData.getBouyData(url);
  currentBouyData.then((text) => {
    const today = new Date();
    let lineDate;
    let line;
    let lineArray;
    const lines = text.split('\n');
    let currentData;

    for (let i = 2; i <= lines.length; i++) {
      line = lines[i];
      lineArray = line.split(' ');
      lineDate = new Date(lineArray[0], lineArray[1] - 1, lineArray[2]).toLocaleDateString();

      if ( today.toLocaleDateString() === lineDate && today.getHours() === parseInt(lineArray[3]) ) {
        currentData = lineArray;
      }
    }
    console.log('currentData after: ', currentData);
. . .
```

I'm expecting currentData to be an array of strings.
I'm getting nothing. Not even a console.log.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Try changing let to var. It may be because the variable currentData and others are not within the scope of for-loop. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Add console.log inside for loop and debug it

Comment: Check your browser console. If the `console.log` is not running, then the promise's `then` callback did not fire. The console might have an error. Also consider adding a `catch` callback.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. If you get no output at all, maybe the `console.log` call never runs, maybe because an earlier line threw an exception.

Comment: `i <= lines.length` suggests you don't know Array's index goes from `0` to `length-1` ... so `for (let i = 2` starts at the THIRD item in the array, and if the array is only 2 long, your code will then probably fail - in fact, it is guaranteed to fail when trying to use `.split` on `undefined` - so console log never will run after the error is thrown

Comment: I limited the for-loop to i <= 24 and it works as expected. There may be a piece of data in this large file that is causing a problem.

Comment: if the array is 25 or longer, then this `<=24` wont fail like `<= lines.length` ... you'd see the error in `Promise.catch()` block if you had one

Comment: read the answer below - it explains the error - as to why you're not getting anything in the console, possibly because you ARE catching the promise error and dealing with it without console output

Comment: I missed that it should have read: ```i < lines.length```. Thanks for the help and extra eyes!

Comment: you dont' care why no error in the console?

Comment: Working on it . . .  :  )

Comment: @skillitzimberg - you probably have a `.catch` block in code you didn't show

Comment: Got it. Had to make the mistakes to learn the lessons.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (let i = 2; i <= lines.length; i++) {
  line = lines[i];
  lineArray = line.split(' ');
  ...
}
console.log('currentData after: ', currentData);
```

The valid indices of an array `arr` are from `0` to `arr.length - 1`.

Your loop condition is `i <= lines.length`, meaning in the last iteration `i` has a value of `lines.length`. `lines[i]` then accesses an element outside of the array bounds, yielding `undefined`.

`lineArray = line.split(' ')` then throws an exception because `undefined` is not an object and `undefined.split` is an error.

That's why the code after the loop is never executed.

Try `i < lines.length`.

Comment: That's it. Loops 101. I knew I was missing something simple. Or was at least hoping so. Thank you.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, because it's not executed, because an exception was thrown earlier.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, but OP didn't mention or ask anything about exceptions. Just `console.log` output. Where did you get that OP saw no error?

Comment: I won't bother any more